How can I place text over image to make it look like placed on object?
I need to add text to this image:

but I want it to look like it placed on the road, so I'll have needed distortion and angle. How can I do this? I can't afford a photoshop (can't do it with other editors too), so I decided I can do this in Blender.

insert a beziercurve along your curve (if you don't have already one), insert a text object with the same origin point.

use your curve in your object data properties of your text object in "text on curve".
result:


Thank you. But it will work only if I have mesh as road. I have just a picture.

that's why  i wrote: insert a beziercurve along your curve/street....

Sorry, I don't get it... Do you mean I should fully re-create scene in 3d?

no, just one beziercurve which follows your street or that "looks" like it follows your street
